# Re-join an ongoing google play multiplayer room

Tags: android, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

Is there a way to allow players to join an ongoing game room when using google play games multiplayer services?
It is mentioned on Google play realtime multiplayer portal that -
https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer
'However, no new players can join a room after it is 'filled' (not even to fill a spot that a participant has vacated).'

But is there any way existing/planned to allow players to join (rather re-join) an ongoing room?
My use case is that if for whatever reason player had to leave the room (eg. onStop), what is the way to re-join him/her to the multiplayer game?